# Crop the image of LaTeX formula

Tags: graphics, equations

How to automatically crop the white space (maximum thickness horizontal/vertical white border) around the formula in image, generated, say, by means of some of online LaTeX formula editors (actually I use EqualX standalone editor)?

For the formula:

```
n_i =
\begin{vmatrix}
p_1^1  & p_1^2  & \dots  & p_1^{i - 1} & 1      & p_1^{i + 1} & \dots  & p_1^D  \\
p_2^1  & p_2^2  & \dots  & p_2^{i - 1} & 1      & p_2^{i + 1} & \dots  & p_2^D  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots      & \vdots & \vdots      & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_D^1  & p_D^2  & \dots  & p_D^{i - 1} & 1      & p_D^{i + 1} & \dots  & p_D^D  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
```

There is an image created:

[image: formula with border]

I specially add the one-pixel black border at the edge of the image to illustrate, that there is a plenty of extra space, which is possible to cut off.

How to do it automatically (maybe by means of imagemagick utility)? There are a bunch of similar images for one-liner formulas, which I want to inline into html-text.

Are there useful commands, which can I prepend into preamble of document, that allows me to atchieve desired?

Comment: Use the `standalone` documentclass

Comment: If you want to use already existing pdfs, use the `pdfcrop` program. It can automatically remove white borders.

Comment: By the way, if you want to embed math into html, you may want to check out [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @KevinC I can't use it in the blog I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `standalone` document class:

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$
n_i =
\begin{vmatrix}
p_1^1  & p_1^2  & \dots  & p_1^{i - 1} & 1      & p_1^{i + 1} & \dots  & p_1^D  \\
p_2^1  & p_2^2  & \dots  & p_2^{i - 1} & 1      & p_2^{i + 1} & \dots  & p_2^D  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots      & \vdots & \vdots      & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_D^1  & p_D^2  & \dots  & p_D^{i - 1} & 1      & p_D^{i + 1} & \dots  & p_D^D  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Not works for me. But maybe the source of failure is invisible fields: in EqualX I can't manage whole the document completely.

Comment: I was mistaken. In the fact, there is a difference in images generated.

Comment: @Orient: So did my answer solve your problem? I'm confused by your comments...

Comment: Yes, your answer partially solve my problem (at least in a spirit of using TeX commands only). It is better if it being possible to remove white border completely (up to last pixel).

Comment: @Orient: Thanks. If you want to crop further, you may change the parameter of `border` to `1pt` or even `0pt`.